# Get input and combo box values and map values to new array, write to Excel

Tags: office-js

I've got about as far as I can on this. I'm playing with a bit of JavaScript code using the Excel JS API. I have two controls: a text box and a combo box. The text box takes a user [number] input, and the drop down lists actions to take (multiply, divide, add, subtract). The gist is I'm taking the current selection and performing the specified action by the specified value, then writing that back to the selection. In Excel, this would be the same as PasteSpecial/Operator.

Here is my JavaScript:

```
$('#mathButton').click(function() {
    callMathify()
        .catch(OfficeHelpers.logError);
});

function callMathify() {
    return Excel.run(function(context) {
        var inputValue = $('#input').val();
        if (inputValue == '') {
            console.log('Please enter a value first!');
        } else {
            var mathType = $('#mathAction').val();
            var selection = context.workbook.getSelectedRange();
            selection.load('values');
            console.log('Input: ' + inputValue + ', Operator: ' + mathType);
            return context.sync()
                .then(function() {
                    var newValues = selection.values.map(row => {
                        if (mathType = 'Multiply') {
                            return row.map(val => {return val * Number($('#input').val())});
                        } else if (mathType = 'Divide') {
                            return row.map(val => {return val / Number(inputValue)});
                        } else if (mathType = 'Add') {
                            return row.map(val => {return val + Number(inputValue)});
                        } else if (mathType = 'Subtract') {
                            return row.map(val => {return val - Number(inputValue)});
                        }
                    });
                    selection.values = newValues;
                    //return context.sync();
            });
        }
        return context.sync();
    });
}
```

I have a simple HTML end for this:

```
<p class="ms-font-m">
    Do some math on all cells in the selection.
    <br>
    Enter a value, choose the action, then click the button.
    <br>
</p>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td><p class="ms-font-m">Value: </p><input type="text" id="input" /></td>
        <td><p class="ms-font-m">Action: </p><select id="mathAction">
            <option value="multiply">Multiply</option>
            <option value="divide">Divide</option>
            <option value="add">Add</option>
            <option value="subtract">Subtract</option>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<br>

<button id="mathButton" class="ms-Button">
    <span class="ms-Button-label">Mathify</span>
</button>
```

I was getting an error about using 'map', but now I'm not getting any error. Anyone see what I'm doing wrong here?

**EDIT**: Replaced the text box references with variable, which I forgot to add prior to posting.

**EDIT**: I adjusted the code according to Jakob's suggestions, and the code works well. I edited the HTML id of the option control to match the case sensitivity of the drop down values (proper casing). The code below works well.

```
$('#mathButton').click(function() {
    callMathify()
        .catch(OfficeHelpers.logError);
});

function callMathify() {
        return Excel.run(function(context) {
            var inputValue = $('#input').val();
            if (inputValue === '') {
                console.log('Please enter a value first!');
                return context.sync();
            } else {
                var selection = context.workbook.getSelectedRange();
                selection.load('values');
                return context.sync()
                    .then(function() {
                        var mathType = $('#mathAction').val();
                        switch (mathType) {
                            case "Multiply":
                                var newValues = selection.values.map(row => {
                                    return row.map(val => {return Number(val) * Number(inputValue)});
                                });
                                break;
                            case "Divide":
                                var newValues = selection.values.map(row => {
                                    return row.map(val => {return Number(val) / Number(inputValue)});
                                });
                                break;
                            case "Add":
                                var newValues = selection.values.map(row => {
                                    return row.map(val => {return Number(val) + Number(inputValue)});
                                });
                                break;
                            case "Subtract":
                                var newValues = selection.values.map(row => {
                                    return row.map(val => {return Number(val) - Number(inputValue)});
                                });
                                break;
                        }
                        selection.values = newValues;
                        console.log('Mathify operation complete! (' + mathType + ')');
                        return context.sync();
                });
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Glad you asked Zack!

There are 3 changes you need to do to make your code snippet work:

- You need to uncomment the context.sync() that you have in the innermost .then() block. That ensures that the selection (range) object is synchronized with Excel and the new values are applied to the selected cells.
- When you compare the value of the drop-down list with a string you need to use the '===' operator.
- The values in the drop-down list control should match what you are using in the comparison since it is case sensitive.

I also notice that your use the inputValue variable for 3 of the cases and $('#input').val() for the first case. I modified your code snippet to use inputValue for all cases.

```
    function callMathify() {
        return Excel.run(function(context) {
            var inputValue = $('#input').val();
            if (inputValue == '') {
                console.log('Please enter a value first!');
            } else {
                var mathType = $('#mathAction').val();
                var selection = context.workbook.getSelectedRange();
                selection.load('values');
                console.log('Input: ' + inputValue + ', Operator: ' + mathType);
                return context.sync()
                    .then(function() {
                        var newValues = selection.values.map(row => {
                            if (mathType === 'multiply') {
                                return row.map(val => {return val * Number(inputValue)});
                            } else if (mathType === 'divide') {
                                return row.map(val => {return val / Number(inputValue)});
                            } else if (mathType === 'add') {
                                return row.map(val => {return val + Number(inputValue)});
                            } else if (mathType === 'subtract') {
                                return row.map(val => {return val - Number(inputValue)});
                            }
                        });
                        selection.values = newValues;
                        return context.sync();
                });
            }        
        });
    }
```

There are also a few changes you can do to make the code more optimized and cleaner. Here are a couple of suggestions:

- Doing the comparisons to the action outside of the .map loop by declaring a function and then using it inside of the loop.
- Using a switch statement instead of the chained if statements.

I will leave that to you to try those changes since it goes beyond your initial question.

Jakob